# Inserting a count of a total into a temp table with a conditional statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

I have some data that looks like so:

```
P     D
1     0
1     0
.63   1
.72   1
etc...
```

Now I have temporary table that takes 3 values and I want to use that first table to create this which holds a total count of these values based on certain conditions.

Here is a statement that does just this but it only works once and I am not great with SQL but could someone tell me how to accomplish something like this but dynamically?

```
INSERT INTO #distribution values(
(SELECT count(P)
FROM myTable
WHERE P > 0.90 AND D = 0), 1, 1)
```

The last 2 values in the temporary table will change based on the condition that is being checked against.

For instance this is another one of my conditionals:

```
WHERE (P BETWEEN 0.80 AND 0.90) AND (D BETWEEN .01 AND .25), 1,2
```

I'm thinking I will need a case statement but can't think of how to accomplish this.

---

**Edit**: There are also some conditions where the other 2 columns will change.

For instance:

```
WHERE (P > 0.90) AND (D BETWEEN .01 AND .25),2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% if I understand, but I think you want something like:

```
INSERT INTO #distribution
SELECT COUNT(1), 1, 1
FROM MyTable
WHERE P > 0.90 AND D = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(1), 1, 2
FROM MyTable
WHERE (P BETWEEN 0.80 AND 0.90) AND (D BETWEEN .01 AND .25)
```

Or you can do something like:

```
SELECT b.TypeCount, a.VALUE1, a.VALUE2
FROM 
   (SELECT 1 AS TypeId, 1 AS VALUE1, 1 AS VALUE2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 1, 2) ValueTable
JOIN  (SELECT CASE WHEN P > 0.90 AND D = 0  THEN 1 
   WHEN (P BETWEEN 0.80 AND 0.90) AND (D BETWEEN .01 AND .25) THEN 2 END AS TypeId,
   COUNT(1) TypeCount
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY SELECT CASE WHEN P > 0.90 AND D = 0  THEN 1 
   WHEN (P BETWEEN 0.80 AND 0.90) AND (D BETWEEN .01 AND .25) THEN 2 END) AS Data
ON Data.TypeId = ValueTable.TypeId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing SQL is not very good at considering this moves into the domain of structured programming instead of transactional. Given that I would go with, as you mentioned, a case statement. Something like this:

```
insert into #distribution
select count(*),
       case t.conditions
        when 1 then 1
        when 2 then 1
        [more conditions...]
       end,
       case t.conditions
        when 1 then 1
        when 2 then 2
        [more conditions...]
       end
from (
    select case
        when P > 0.90 and D = 0 then 1
        when P >= 0.80 and P <= 0.90 and D >= .01 and D <= .25 then 2
        [more conditions...]
    end as conditions
    from myTable
    ) as t
group by conditions
```

Comment: This might be what I want. Ill try it out thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
insert into #distribution(col1, col2, col3)
    select count(*), 1, grp
    from (select (case when P > 0.90 and D = 0 then 1
                       when P >= 0.80 and P <= 0.90 and D >= .01 and D <= .25 then 2
                  end) as grp
          from myTable
        ) as t
    where grp is not null
    group by grp;
```

Note:  You should list the columns for an `insert`.